# Word meaning: A slip of the tongue which suggests how you actually feel, often humorous

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm sure there's a word which matches this definition. Where you make a slight mistake in saying something and a friend will nudge you and say "oh, so *that's* what you *really* think?!"

One example, though not perfect, was when Prime Minister Gordon Brown, in a heated exchange, *meant* to declare "We saved the banks" but actually said "We saved the world..." before correcting himself.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: I'm trying to think of one but my mind has helpfully gone blank.

Comment: Vaguely related: you may also be thinking of a _spoonerism_

Comment: Sorry all. I didn't know if it was a single word or not and being new, was unsure what tags to use. Both phrases and single-word answers are welcome, what ever is accurate. Apologies if you feel messed about, that wasn't my intention.

Comment: So categorically, 'parapraxis' is _an_ answer but I think _the_ answer should reference both

Comment: Great example (in a joke): Man says to his psychiatrist "Last week you were telling me about Freudian slips, and I had the most amazing one this week.  We were at my in-laws for dinner.  I wanted to say to my mother-in-law 'Please pass the salt' but it came out as 'you ruined my life' "

Comment: Ha ha, that was a Freudian whip! Whoops, there's a mother!

Comment: @Mr.Boy I think you need to edit in examples of how you intend to use the phrase to have your question reopened and keep it open afterwards. Would the following be suitable? Feel free to edit them in. “He is obnoxious, brutish, sexy… I mean sexist.” “Sexy, huh? Was that a ___________? Is that how you really feel about him?” This closely matches your firs example. For the second: some interpreted Gordon Brown’s mistake as a __________, reflecting his craving for recognition.”

Answer (score 105, accepted):

That's an example of [*Freudian slip* (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip):

> error in speech, memory, or physical action that is interpreted as occurring due to the interference of an unconscious ("dynamically repressed") subdued wish, conflict, or train of thought guided by the ego and the rules of correct behavior.

It is also known, technically, I suppose, as [*parapraxis* (dictionary.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parapraxis):

> a slip of the tongue or pen, forgetfulness, misplacement of objects, or other error thought to reveal unconscious wishes or attitudes.

Comment: Darn it! Thirty seconds late! Anyway, +1

Comment: +1 You are right in as much as that is what it is usually called. However modern *cognitive* psychologists place little reliance on Freud's theory about the existence of an ordered sub-conscious - mainly because it relies too much on theory, and there is little empirical evidence for such a thing.

Comment: @WS2 Good point. I guess that's why you have "interpreted as"  in Wikipedia, and "thought to" in dictionary .com

Comment: A Freudian slip is when you say one thing and mean your mother -- I mean "another"

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest too. And it doesn't have to be verbal. You can do it in writing too: In an email to a colleague I misspelled another guys name consistently as Dubious in stead of Dubios without realizing it. My colleague also didn't notice. (Mr. Dubois wasn't very easy to work with... So it felt "right".) About a year later another colleague (who didn't know of our earlier slip of the pen) did exactly the same thing.

Comment: @WS2 Unfortunately the absence of empirical evidence doesn't always prevent the adoption of a statement as truth...for evidence, just look to people who believe the earth is flat, evolution is a hoax, or gluten free diets are healthy for everyone and not just people with gluten allergies...

Comment: My experience has been that the term "Freudian slip" typically refers specifically to gaffs of a sexual nature.  This may not be the official definition, but it seems to be widely used in that way.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I don't know if you intended it (If so, +1!) but what's hilarious is that your statement is both self-referential, _and_ a Freudian slip. A [gaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error#Gaffe) is a mistake, while a gaff is [something else entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-sexe).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist - Hmm, I'd like to pretend that was on purpose, but having never heard of the other definition until now, I can honestly say that was entirely unintentional.  But admittedly hilarious.  (Can you still call it a Freudian slip if the person who makes it is unaware even subconsciously of alternate meaning?)

Comment: I once attended a wedding where the pastor meant to say that the bride and groom were "present" but instead said "pregnant." (Fortunately the couple were very good sports about it, and no, they weren't actually pregnant.) That, I would say, is a classic example of a "Freudian" slip: unintended, appropriate to the situation, and usually hilarious.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The main reason for that is because Freud related a lot of things to sex (one of his main theories was the 'psychosexual stages' which is incidentally the origin of the phrase 'to be anal'). In its original meaning a Freudian slip was generally about sexual things, but it became generalised. (My low-level psychology qualification comes in handy once more, huzzah!)

Comment: A Freudian slip is where you say one thing, but really mean a mother. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Another word for it is **Lapsus**.

[According to Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapsus)

> A lapsus (Latin for "lapse, slip, error") is an involuntary mistake made while writing or speaking, something long studied in philology.

The word is used in quite a few languages.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Fun answer, I'd never heard of this before.

Comment: It's often used in French too!

Comment: +1 the same latin term has seeped into several Roman-group languages too (pt/es: Lapso, fr: Lapse, it: Lasse and so on)

Comment: Not used in eveyday English.

Comment: The term *lapsus* is neutral: unlike Jacinto's suggestions, and unlike what the OP is asking for, it does not specifically imply that the error suggests a desire or belief that the speaker had intended to conceal.

Comment: For sure it doesn't fit the definition as well as *Freudian Slip*: not as much used, and more technical than something to joke about. But it exists, and existed before freudian slip :)

Comment: What's wrong with just plain 'lapse'? If you use 'lapsus'' in English, unless you're writing catachismic exegesis, you'll be way out of register.

Comment: Did you mean prolapse?

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton uh prolapse is when one of your organs slips out of place. usually used when referring to the anus.

Comment: I know this word is used in this context in Spanish and French but I have never heard it used so in English. While the intended meaning might be inferred from its similarity to words like _lapse_ or from knowledge of the Latin meaning, to my knowledge, it is not a word normally used to describe a slip of the tongue in English.

Comment: @Insane oh that's really gross/bad

Answer (score 13):

A [Kinsley Gaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_gaffe) where a person, especially a politician, accidentally says what they really think.

Answer (score 7):

> Many a truth is said in jest.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many_a_true_word_is_spoken_in_jest), this adage is from the Cook’s Tale by Chaucer.

This is not necessarily a *slip*, though it often is. In some cases, the joke was planned, not a slip, but by making the joke the speaker *unintentionally* gives away that he or she isn’t really joking.

But it doesn’t generally apply when a joke is obviously speaking the truth. Observational humor, satire, etc., wouldn’t usually be described with this, even though the literal meaning would apply especially well in those cases.

Comment: I did not know that was Chaucerian!  good one